Cauchy principal value for a Gaussian integral of a rational function
I wish to calculate integrals of the following form, all Gaussian integrals of a rational function, on the entire real domain:
$$ I_{k,n} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} dx \frac{e^{-x^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \frac{x^k}{p_n(x)}$$
where $p_n(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$.
Do those have a name? (if not, we might name them Cohen integrals of the $\{k,n\}$ kind :)
Obviously, those are not proper integrals due to the divergence at the roots of $p$, so I'm thinking "Cauchy's principal value", but numerically I see they are well-defined. Are there known conditions for the existence of Cauchy's principal value in this case?
